# component.getMouseMotionListener return more than one

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I added one MouseMotionListener to the JTextField. But when I use `jf.getMouseMotionListeners().length` to know about how many mouse listeners are registered then I get 3!!. That's causing me some problem because I'm trying to add a listener depending on that length. If its zero I add or else I don't want to add a listener.

Below is the code and I have written code to know the length in mouse moved event.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    final JTextPane jf = new JTextPane ();
    jf.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

                 System.out.println(jf.getMouseListeners().length);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    jf.setBounds(30,30,100,50);
    fr.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fr.setLayout(null);

    fr.add(jf);
    fr.setVisible(true);
}
```

Why is that length 3 when I added just one listener? 
is there a better way to check whether a listener on a component is registered or not?

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I should be able to drag the JTextPane any where inside window and I should be able to edit it by double clicking on the JTextPane .

If I have a drag listener while editing and If wan't to select a text to style it the JTextPane gets dragged instead of selecting a text from JTextPane.

Now I want to remove the motionlistener when I am in editing mode and add it when I'm not editing.

So thats why I'm trying to remove it or in simple I need to disable the motionlistener.

Comment: Why do you want to add a listener based on whether there already is one? Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: @tbodt If I add more than one listener it creates a wrong behavior when I actually drag the component.

Comment: _I'm trying to add a listener depending on that length._ Dont! By design, listeners must be independent and unaware of who else is listening.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Where is your code?

Comment: how volatile your question is, isn't it, there is only issue to recording double click, or double_click enabled DND

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry about that. I was actually asked what I was trying to do and thats why I posted those. My concern was and is about adding and removing listeners by checking about whether is there a listener registered or not.

Comment: you wouldn't need that, those Listeners[] aren't important for your requirement (sure valid untill your question will be changed), because all together are about Document & Caret, havent' something with DND, moving with JComponent inside container

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager.

Comment: @kleopatra I really don't have any idea about _unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever_. Please can you bit more elaborate on why shouldn't I do it. I have this need and I have to do it. If there is a better way can you please suggest me?

Comment: @kleopatra what about cases when you are impleemnting editor where user can place components e.g. by D&D? Shapes, textboxes etc.? How LayoutManager can help? "don't do it ... ever" is too strict, right?

Comment: @StanislavL your words gave me some strength. I was so scared and I was eagerly looking for a comment from Kleopatra.

Comment: @StanislavL we already had [this discussion elsewhere](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374), didn't we :-) Though don't remember if any of the numbers is you ...

Comment: no reason to be scared - there's always the odd corner case where rules don't apply :-) Anyway, even then it would be a good idea to factor all the sizing/locating code where it belongs, aka: into a custom LayoutManager. See Rob's DragLayout (don't have the link handy, but google should help to find it)

Comment: @kleopatra that is a useful comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- output is correct, JTextField has another notifiers implemented API, they are notified from added MouseListener
- see whats debuger returns

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseAndJTextField {

    private JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    private JTextField jf = new JTextField(20);

    public MouseAndJTextField() {
        jf.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(jf.getMouseListeners().length);
            }
        });
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.add(jf);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MouseAndJTextField fs = new MouseAndJTextField();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your class (inner class) instead of the Anonymous inner class for the listener and go through the listeners calling instanceof to find whether your instance is added.

Alternatively you can define a flag indicating whether the listener should process event or not. Set the flag by default to true. Set to false when you have to skip event (in your edit mode) and reset after.

Comment: +1 I think s/he want to allow DND from mouse Double_Click, but there is UIResource as inputMap, I'm never going inside ....

Comment: please is there option to switch with enabled/editable for JTextPane (protect Document) on mouse double click by allowing DND, another double_click to reset this status back, isn't there another issue with InputMap and MouseEvents, now to ignore quite users non_friendly